# "Up" is adjective or adverb in this context

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

Sentences:

> 1. Further **up the hill** there was a small house.
> 2. Further **up in the hill**  there was a small house.
> 3. He is **up** the tree.
> 4. He is **up**  in the tree.

In example *2 and 4,*  **up** seems to be **an adjective,** is it so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

> Further *up the hill* there was a small house.

Here 'up' is functioning as a preposition.  The Prep. phrase is functioning as an adjective modifying 'house' as part of the adverb phrase "further up in the hill"

> Further **up** *in the hill* there was a small house.

Here 'up' is an adjective modifying 'house' while 'further' and 'in the hill' are modifying 'up', both part of the adverb phrase "further up in the hill".

> He is *up the tree*.

Clearly a prepositional phrase functioning as an adjective.

> He is **up** *in the tree*.

Here 'up' is the predicate adjective modified by 'in the tree'.

See [Entry 2 #3 in Webster's Online Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up) for further examples of 'up' being used as an adjective and being modified by a prepositional phrase.

---

If you need to explain #2 or #4 to another person, a good way to do so would be to test it by removing the prepositional phrase.  Doing so does not change the meaning of "up" and the sentence remains grammatical.

> Further up, there was a small house.

We can also move 'further up' to other parts of the sentence without the prepositional phrase, as the headword of the adverb phrase is 'further'.

> He is up.

Here, 'up' is describing the subject pronoun.  This creates a little amiguity because generally we use 'up' to mean "awake" in a sentence like this, but the original meaning of "being higher" is still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

[1] *[Further up the hill] there was a small house*.

[2] *[Further up in the hill] there was a small house*.

[3] *He is [up the tree]*.

[4] *He is [further up in the tree].*

No: "up" is not an adjective; it's a preposition, but its function in [1] and [3] is not the same as in [2] and [4].

In [1] and [3] the preposition "up" functions as **head** of the bracketed PPs functioning as locative complement of "be". The adverb "further" in [1] modifies "up".

In [2] and [4] the directional preposition "up" functions as pre-head **modifier** of "in" within  the bracketed PPs. The adverb "further" then modifies "up".